# How to execute off-site javascript that's dynamically inserted with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically change the source of an embedded script, but am having trouble.

Here is an example of my html:

```
<div id="inner"> 
   <script src='http://affiliate-website/1'></script>
</div>
```

When my page loads like this, it works perfectly.

But I'm trying to dynamically change that script's source based on user location.

When someone visits from location B, I want the script source to change to:

`http://affiliate-website/2`

So after some browsing around, I found this snippet almost did what I wanted:

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://affiliate-website/2";
$("div#inner").append(script);
```

That produces the following html:

```
<div id="inner"> 
   <script src='http://affiliate-website/2'></script>
</div>
```

The problem is, that script tag is present, but it's not executing the script as it does when I just put that straight into my html. I think it has something to do with loading (as in when it's in my html file, it's loading earlier than when it's produced with this snippet?) but I don't know.

Comment: The script will load asynchronously relative to the code that is updating the `<div>`. Also you don't need the "type" attribute; JavaScript is the default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the type attribute. Regarding the asynchronous loading, do you have a suggestion on how I can make it load in a similar manner as it does when I just type that script directly into my html file?

Comment: Well you really can't.  What you *can* do is use something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) to load the script and provide a way to execute code when the script is ready.